# How do I create a single text URL in storyboard using Xcode 11? If done in code, all of my interface is erased except for the coded textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I want to display this text with Sign Up as a clickable link in Xcode 11:

[image: view of text]

All of the buttons in this storyboard have been created in storyboard. I came across a solution that involved coding...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Don't have an account? Sign up.")
         attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://udacity.com", range: NSRange(location: 23, length: 8))

         webSignUp.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
        return false
    }
```

...but this makes my already created buttons disappear.

How can I create a link in storyboard using Xcode 11? Or create a link in coding that doesn't interfere with everything else?

Comment: Provided `webSignUp` is the outlet in the scene your code should be giving you the desired results unless you have something really strange in the constraints or something. As an experiment try adding a call to `super` in `viewDidLoad` and when the the app is running use the UI Debugger to make sure your buttons haven't just been hidden or pushed off screen.

Comment: Hi, you need to apply this to the UILabel or UITextView not for UITextField

Comment: I changed it UILabel but now the link doesn't work.

Comment: "but this makes my already created buttons disappear." why? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using **TextEdit.app**, that little app that manage RichText, can be used for Attributed String & Storyboard.

Open the app, write your text, select the part of the text where you'll need a link. *Edit/Add link...*, add your link.

Open **Xcode.app**, select your *UITextView* in your *Storyboard*, then copy/paste the text from *TextEdit.app* into the the *UITextView*.

Since the *WYSIWYG* might be strange sometimes and the Xcode one isn't user friendly at all, do not hesitate to right click on the Storyboard, *Open As/Source code*, find your text, (you can search for `key="NSLink"`, or simply the text you put, the link, etc.)

You should see :

```
<textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" usesAttributedText="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NxY-fQ-0iH">
    <rect key="frame" x="87" y="331" width="240" height="128"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
    <attributedString key="attributedText">
        <fragment content="Don’t have an account? ">
            <attributes>
                <font key="NSFont" metaFont="user"/>
                <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0" allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation="NO">
                    <tabStops>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="28.299999237060547">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="56.650001525878906">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="85">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="113.34999847412109">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="141.69999694824219">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="170.05000305175781">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="198.39999389648438">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="226.75">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="255.10000610351562">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="283.45001220703125">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="311.79998779296875">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="340.14999389648438">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                    </tabStops>
                </paragraphStyle>
            </attributes>
        </fragment>
        <fragment content="Sign up">
            <attributes>
                <font key="NSFont" metaFont="user"/>
                <url key="NSLink" string="http://stackoverflow.com"/>
                <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0" allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation="NO">
                    <tabStops>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="28.299999237060547">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="56.650001525878906">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="85">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="113.34999847412109">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="141.69999694824219">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="170.05000305175781">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="198.39999389648438">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="226.75">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="255.10000610351562">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="283.45001220703125">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="311.79998779296875">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="340.14999389648438">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                    </tabStops>
                </paragraphStyle>
            </attributes>
        </fragment>
        <fragment content=".">
            <attributes>
                <font key="NSFont" metaFont="user"/>
                <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="left" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0" allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation="NO">
                    <tabStops>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="28.299999237060547">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="56.650001525878906">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="85">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="113.34999847412109">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="141.69999694824219">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="170.05000305175781">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="198.39999389648438">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="226.75">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="255.10000610351562">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="283.45001220703125">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="311.79998779296875">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                        <textTab alignment="left" location="340.14999389648438">
                            <options/>
                        </textTab>
                    </tabStops>
                </paragraphStyle>
            </attributes>
        </fragment>
    </attributedString>
    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
</textView>
```

It's quite verbose, especially all the tabstop/textTab but you might edit your context from there (like changing the link).

Comment: TextEditor just crashes on my system before it gets to the document screen.

Comment: I meant TextEdit.app (I mistyped and saw that there is a TexEditor.app) we’re good on that? It’s a default app on macOS. Else find your textview in source code of the storyboard and copy/paste my code where it makes sense

Comment: I copied over your code, and the text is not clickable. :(

Comment: I didn't focused on that, because I was looking for "how to set it in Storyboard, but did you put the other properties to make it work https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview ? ie selectable to true & editable to false? And did you set the delegate of the textview? Is then your delegate method called?